# @auth0/auth0-spa-js isAuthenticated is undefined on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, next.js, auth0, server-side-rendering

I am working on the authentication of my app and I have managed to add login to my page. Users are able to login and their session is stored however as soon as I refresh the page their session is gone. 
ReactJs + NextJS

I know there is **getTokenSilently** but it will return this when I call it!

```
error: "login_required"
error_description: "Login required"
state: "N3B+aWt4T1dBeGlibWsua2ZkdX5LTzR6T19ndTdXfkJ2Tm5kUzJIY3lXTQ=="
```

What am I doing wrong here?

- My profile page!

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== `undefined`) {
      if (!loading && !isAuthenticated) {
        loginWithRedirect({})
      }
    }
  });
```

- Home page which shows an icon if user is logged in!

```
          <Button
            className="account-button"
            variant="textButton"
            icon={<i className="flaticon-user" />}
            aria-label="login"
            title={loading ? 'loading' : isAuthenticated ? 'Hi' : 'login'}
          />
```

- Auth service

```
// src/react-auth0-spa.js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import createAuth0Client from "@auth0/auth0-spa-js";

const DEFAULT_REDIRECT_CALLBACK = () =>
  window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, window.location.pathname);

export const Auth0Context = React.createContext();
export const useAuth0 = () => useContext(Auth0Context);
export const Auth0Provider = ({
  children,
  onRedirectCallback = DEFAULT_REDIRECT_CALLBACK,
  ...initOptions
}) => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState();
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const [auth0Client, setAuth0] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [popupOpen, setPopupOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const initAuth0 = async () => {
      const auth0FromHook = await createAuth0Client(initOptions);
      setAuth0(auth0FromHook);

      if (window.location.search.includes("code=") &&
          window.location.search.includes("state=")) {
        const { appState } = await auth0FromHook.handleRedirectCallback();
        onRedirectCallback(appState);
      }

      const isAuthenticated = await auth0FromHook.isAuthenticated();

      setIsAuthenticated(isAuthenticated);

      if (isAuthenticated) {
        const user = await auth0FromHook.getUser();
        setUser(user);
      }

      setLoading(false);
    };
    initAuth0();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  const loginWithPopup = async (params = {}) => {
    setPopupOpen(true);
    try {
      await auth0Client.loginWithPopup(params);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } finally {
      setPopupOpen(false);
    }
    const user = await auth0Client.getUser();
    setUser(user);
    setIsAuthenticated(true);
  };

  const handleRedirectCallback = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    await auth0Client.handleRedirectCallback();
    const user = await auth0Client.getUser();
    setLoading(false);
    setIsAuthenticated(true);
    setUser(user);
  };
  return (
    <Auth0Context.Provider
      value={{
        isAuthenticated,
        user,
        loading,
        popupOpen,
        loginWithPopup,
        handleRedirectCallback,
        getIdTokenClaims: (...p) => auth0Client.getIdTokenClaims(...p),
        loginWithRedirect: (...p) => auth0Client.loginWithRedirect(...p),
        getTokenSilently: (...p) => auth0Client.getTokenSilently(...p),
        getTokenWithPopup: (...p) => auth0Client.getTokenWithPopup(...p),
        logout: (...p) => auth0Client.logout(...p)
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Auth0Context.Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was using Brave Browser!!!!!! Detailed description here:

> Right. So the silent authentication issue, the “login required” error, is what you get when your browser does not, or cannot, send the “auth0” cookie. This is the cookie that Auth0 leaves on the browser client once the user has a session with Auth0, i.e. the user has logged in through an interactive flow. You should be able to confirm this by looking at the network logs or analyzing the HAR output. The scenarios that work will have the cookie attached, whereas the ones that fail will not. If that’s the case, this is neither a sample nor SDK issue as they are not involved in the setting of that cookie; it is issued by the authorization server.
>
> If the browser cannot sent this cookie, it’s most likely because of some software or browser extension or something which is blocking third-party tracking cookies. Safari does this by default thanks to its Intelligent Tracking Prevention (ITP2) 1 software that is built-in. This can explain why silent auth works in Chrome’s incognito mode but not in normal mode. If you’re running some extensions, you might want to disable some of them to narrow down which one is preventing the cookie from being sent.
>
> What I can’t readily explain is how it works in Safari’s Private mode, as I thought ITP2 would block such cookies regardless. Let me get some clarity on that.

https://community.auth0.com/t/failed-silent-auth-login-required/33165/24

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing it with the rest of community!